# FullCalendar shows all google calendar events at current time and date

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, gcal

Instead of showing our events, FullCalendar creates elements starting at the current date/time. I've tried this with multiple google calendars (public, custom, etc) and always get the same result.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [{
        url:'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/jcornelius.com_e9lk2eh1p3tdn3v775l0e0v48g%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
        dataType : 'jsonp'
    }]
});
```

[image]

See this fiddle to reproduce the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/jcornelius/pba56nf1/

Comment: Please embed the example code here, using the *snippet* feature of Stack Overflow, and remove the JSfiddle link.

Comment: Also, your JSfiddle freezes the browser for quite some time … maybe you could create a different example with a leaner dataset. This would significantly decrease the urge to leave this question as soon as the browser is usable again.

Comment: @lxg The slow response on the fiddle is because of the issue I describe. Sorry for that. Thanks for the pointer and edit of the post. I couldn't add more than two links because I didn't have enough mojo or karma or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your sources and at least the example data works. Yours on the other hand seem to be invalid data or something? I'll try to help if the problem persists.

http://jsfiddle.net/pba56nf1/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        events: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
        //events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/jcornelius.com_e9lk2eh1p3tdn3v775l0e0v48g%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
        eventClick: function(event) {
            // opens events in a popup window
            window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
            return false;
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The strange thing is you can cURL the XML feed link and it returns the event data. It just seems to fail on the AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the permissions issue was an error with the Google calendar. I contacted Google support and they reset the permissions. Now with Richard Hermanson's answer above everything works.